# Rails admin create object when creating another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I'm using rails-admin for admin panel in my app and i have model Cell which has few fields one of this is "title" and i have another model is Category which has title too. So i want to create a Category object every time when Cell object creates from admin panel with the same title. How can i manage creating objects from rails-admin?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far? What behaviour/errors are you seeing?

Comment: Your current question is far too vague; I can't provide a proper response without seeing what you're trying currently. `Category.create(title: params[:title])`??

Comment: in rails admin i have
  config.model Cell do
    list do
      exclude_fields :_id
    end
  end
and i don't know where is programm going when i press "save" on creating cell so i can't handle anything when this acts

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific to `ActiveAdmin`. You can accomplish this in several ways.

However, I suggest using [rails callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to achieve this. For example, you can create `after_create` hook on `Cell` model (living in `app/models` I suppose) which would look something like this:

`after_create :create_category`
...
...

`def create_category
  Category.create(title: title)
end`

Comment: it's a solution) but i don't know is this the best